The bundle structure on $E/G = \bigcup_{x\in M} E_x/G_x$
I'm learning about the bundle structure on $E/G$ where $E$ is a vector bundle over $M$, and $G$ is a subbundle. I've reproduced my understanding below and asked some questions. Thanks for your help!

Suppose $E$ is a vector bundle over $M$, with $p: E\to M$ as the bundle projection. Let $G\subset E$ be a subbundle of $E$ (over $M$), such that $\dim G_x = k$ and $\dim E_x = n$ for all $x\in M$, where $G_x,E_x$ denote the respective fibers $\left(p\vert_G\right)^{-1}(x)$ and $p^{-1}(x)$. Define $E/G := \bigcup_{x\in M} E_x/G_x$ and let $q: E/G\to M$ be the obvious projection. To show that $E/G$ is a vector bundle, we require a cover by local trivializations.
To begin, consider a local trivialization for the bundle $E$, i.e., an open set $U$ such that $\phi: U\times\Bbb R^n \to p^{-1}(U)$ is a homeomorphism. Let $p_1$ denote the projection from $U\times\Bbb R^n$ to $U$. For each $x\in U$, $G_x \subset p^{-1}(x) \subset p^{-1}(U)$ is a $k$-dimensional vector space. Then, $\phi^{-1}(G_x)$ is also a $k$-dimensional vector space, and we can find $A_x\in GL_n(\Bbb R)$ such that $A_x(\Bbb R^k \times\{\mathbf{0}\}) = \phi^{-1}(G_x)$. Define $\widetilde\phi(x,v) = \phi(x,A_x(v))$. Since $A_x$ is invertible, $\widetilde\phi$ is also a homeomorphism from $U\times\Bbb R^n$ to $p^{-1}(U)$.


Why is $\phi^{-1}(G_x)$ a $k$-dimensional vector space?


$\widetilde\phi$ induces a homeomorphism $\widehat{\phi}: U\times \Bbb R^{n-k} \to q^{-1}(U)$, so $E/G$ is an $(n-k)$-vector bundle.


Any two elements of the quotient $U\times \Bbb R^{n-k} \cong U \times \Bbb R^n/\Bbb R^k$ are in the same equivalence class if their last $(n-k)$-coordinates are identical. In this case, $\widetilde\phi$ sends them to the same element in $p^{-1}(U)$, so we have a map $\widetilde{\widetilde{\phi}}: U\times\Bbb R^{n-k} \to p^{-1}(U)$. How does this give us $\widehat{\phi}$, and why is $\widehat{\phi}$ a homeomorphism?

